# Why does the Calendar class not have a public constructor?

Tags: java

Will `new Calendar()` have any difference from `Calendar.getInstance()`?

The question is just as simple as it is........... Since the system refuse to post it, I just copy some nonsense here.

```
private static Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
public static int getCalendar(long time, int calendarConst) {
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
    return calendar.get(calendarConst);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to read the source of `Calendar.getInstance()` to see what actually happens there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a detailed account of the difference between constructors and static factory methods in Effective Java second edition, which is well worth a read.

The main difference here is in what the two return:

- The constructor always returns a non-null instance of the specific class on which the constructor is invoked, or it throws an exception and you don't get a reference to the part-constructed instance;
- A static factory method can return a subclass or null (or it throws an exception).

The latter case is exactly what `Calendar.getInstance()` does: you clearly don't get back an instance of `Calendar` itself, since it is abstract, but instead you might get a `GregorianCalendar`, `JapaneseImperialCalendar` etc.

This decouples `Calendar`'s implementation from the client code: you can make changes to `Calendar` without the client needing to make changes.

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is simple [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) is an Abstract class, so we cant create an instance of it. Now when you call `Calendar.getInstance` then `GregorianCalendar` instance is created.

Comment: No idea why they made this class Abstract. But there you go.

Comment: Just to add that Calendar.getInstance() also has constructors which are protected. Now the reason that its constructors are protected and not private is to allow subclasses to extend it. Now since the constructors are protected, only classes in the same package can extend Calendar.

Comment: @bijiDango Please look at the list of in-use calendars here http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_calendars and then say which one you think should be represented by Calendar, the non-abstract class; then think about whether the other calendars would really be subtypes of that.

Comment: @Rahul any subclass in any package can access a protected constructor.

Comment: @RahulTripathi *"Now since the constructors are protected, only classes in the same package can extend Calendar."* Nonsense. Any class can extend `Calendar`.

Answer (score -1):

When you do `new Calendar()`, it creates new calendar instance from the default Calendar instance. Sometimes creating an instance via constructor is not good as creating from Factory methods. That's why it uses Factory methods to create an instance.

And,

`Calendar.getInstance()` is a native method, and **note down native methods don't have body/implementation.** They have implemented already from the system.

It writes here: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html.

And, as explained in above answers already, the calendar instance is created by calling Calendar class. Static Factory design pattern to create calendar instance.

Comment: `Calendar.getIstance` is not native method, at least not in all java implementations

Comment: @Enerccio, I meant, the Java system gets the Calendar instance from the OS (Operating System). All the method implemented OS are native methods. Since JVM depends on OS to get Calendar instance, and Calendar itself is a native to OS, all the native instance methods are native by automatically. I didn't mean they are native method based on Java native methods defn. Hope you understood. I was not talking the native keyword here. But I agree this is not clear. The same word has multiple contextual meanings. Bear this in mind.